# CSS Difference on Android 4.4 WebView and Chrome Browser for Android

Tags: google-chrome, webview, android-webview, css

Trying to implement a style for a WebApp.
It seems that the CSS propery 'line-height' is different in the WebView.

I used this pen as example: http://codepen.io/bbredewold/pen/gGbht

The code is nothing special:

```
.flip {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.front {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font: 6em arial;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #b4b4b4;
}

<div class="flip">
  <div class="front">A</div>
</div>
```

Is this a bug? Or do I miss something?
Any ideas how to work around this? It's a headbreaker...
These are pictures with the differences. Picture 1 is problematic, picture 2 is nicely centered...

[image: Android WebView (Chromium)]

[image: Chrome for Android]

Comment: Which version of Android is this? As of Android 4.4, the web view is powered by the Chrome engine.

Comment: Yes, It's 4.4. So that's why I expected it should be the same!

Answer (score 2):

(I can't comment the original question, as my score is currently too low)

I realize this is a slightly old question but here goes:

I ran into something similar recently (Android 6, Chrome 55 etc) and I found that some of the Web Settings for WebView can make it interpret the page *as if* you had used the viewport metatag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

In order to get the same result in Chrome I had to insert that viewport metatag.